# Is there a way to control WSDL names in Spring Boot auto-generated WSDL file?

Tags: spring, boot

Modify WSDL port name, service name and binding name, in Spring Boot application using DefaultWsdl11Definition

I am modifying a service that the existing names cannot change due to contractual agreement with client written in COBOL. Therefore I need fine grained control over the names that Spring Boot automatically assigns to an auto-generated WSDL. I tried making adjustments in DefaultWsdl11Definition but this class only allows changing the Port Type name, which Spring then changes the service name inside the WSDL and also changes the binding name. According to Soap11Provider JavaDocs it allows modifying SOAP actions defined in the WSDL:

> Soap11Provider JavaDoc- By setting the soapActions property, the SOAP Actions defined in the resulting WSDL can be set. Additionaly, the transport uri can be changed from the default HTTP transport by using the transportUri property.

However, I can't find any example of how to add a custom implementation of the class into my application. This is what I've tried-

```
@Bean
public Soap11Provider defaultProvider() {
    Soap11Provider provider = new Soap11Provider();
    provider.setServiceName("TestService");
    return provider;
}
```

Can someone help to show me if I am going down the right/wrong path, or if there is any example on how to take more control of WSDL names?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the service name using DefaultWsdl11Definition, which satisfies this question. I was not able to change the binding name which I'm still interested in trying to solve but I'll reference the documentation for wsdl4j for that.

```
@Bean
public Wsdl11Definition definition() {
    Wsdl11Definition definition = new Wsdl11Definition ();
    definition.setServiceName("Service");
    return definition;
}
```